# Can Bash History Expansion be used to reference something in the same command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Bash has this feature called history expansion where you can use shortcuts that expand to things you've typed previously into bash.

Example:  `!! - expands into previous command`

```
$> rm -f /var/log/access.log
rm: /var/log/access.log: Permission Denied
$> sudo !!
sudo rm -f /var/log/access.log
$> echo "i am teh hax"
```

Another: `!$ - expands into last arg of previous command`

```
$> echo "no one was here" > access.log
$> cp !$ /var/log/
cp access.log /var/log/
```

Does bash, or some other shell, have the ability to use substitution shortcuts  within the command itself?

Something like

```
$> cp httpd.conf !$.bak
cp httpd.conf httpd.conf.bak
$> echo "SABOTEUR!!!" > httpd.conf
```

I need to up my 1980's cyberpunk skills.  Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by within the command itself, do you mean you want to refer to `httpd.conf`?

Then this is your solution in [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/298081/in-bash-how-can-i-rename-a-file-without-repeating-the-path)

Using bash [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators):

```sh
mv path/to/oldfile !#:1:h/newfile
```

where `!#:1:h` means: from the line you're currently typing (`!#`), take the first word (`:1`), then take only the path component (`:h` -- the head) from it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by justhalf is what you want.

But for your requirement, there is one more hack/misuse available.

```
sed -i.bak '' /path/to/file
```

e.g.

```
sed -i.bak '' httpd.conf
```

It will copy your file to another file with .bak appended.

Advantage: `/path/to/file` can contain wildcards/globs, or you can directly give a white-space separated list of files.